# ListView ItemTapEvent using MVVMLight

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

I am trying to build an application using `Xamarin Forms` and `MVVMLight`. I have created master detail page with the menu items. 
when user taps on the menu item i want to navigate the page. Now the problem is to create the `ItemTapped` event for `ListView` using `MVVMLight`
i tried to find over web but could not get the proper answer that really works.

so far i tried to implement `EventToCommand` using `MVVMLight` but xaml is throwing error by saying

> The attachable property Behaviors was not found in type Interaction

```
<ListView 
            ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItemsList}"            
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"           
            Margin="0,0,0,10"
            RowHeight="110"
            SeparatorVisibility="Default"
            x:Name="MenuList"

            >
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <i:BehaviorCollection>
                    <cmd:EventToCommand EventName="ItemSelected" Command="{Binding OnTapCommand}"                                   
                </i:BehaviorCollection>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
              <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                    </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
</ListView>
```

namespaces that i am using are mentioned below

> xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
>   xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras"

when i was not using `MVVMLight` i used to use custom behavior such as `behaviors:ItemTappedCommandBehavior.ItemTappedCommand="{Binding OnContactSelectCommand}"`

but i really don't know how to do the same with the `MVVMLight`. I am trying to run the mobile app on **android and iOS platform**

Comment: Somehow I always use the SelectedItem="{Binding ***}" binding to trigger the menu selection. So in your VM in the SelectedItem property, trigger the navigation checking the menu option selected.

Comment: With `MVVMLight` ? can you explain how ?

Comment: Extend your XAML ListView code with <ListView 
            ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItemsList}"            
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"           
            Margin="0,0,0,10"
            RowHeight="110"
            SeparatorVisibility="Default"
            x:Name="MenuList"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenuItem"> and add that Property in your VM. It will get the selected value each time the user taps and item in the menu

Comment: okay let me try by setting `RelayCommand<MenuItems> SelectedMenuItem`

Comment: Wait I'll stub it out in an answer... because you don't need the a command at all...

Answer (score 1):

When showing items in a ListView for a menu, you can just leverage the build in functionality of a ListView to know what the user 'selected'.

In other words, just bind the SelectedItem property of the ListView to a property in your VM.
In that property setter you can code your logic to trigger the correct page navigation.

So the XAML should look like:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItemsList}"
          CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
          Margin="0,0,0,10"
          RowHeight="110"
          SeparatorVisibility="Default"
          x:Name="MenuList"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenuItem}">
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView>
```